# How to UploadVideos to Youtube Programatically from Android App

Tags: android, programming-languages, youtube, youtube-api

I would like to know that how can I upload videos to youtube from my android application programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use YouTube API in your application http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Sending_a_Browser_Upload_API_Request

Comment: yes i know about that youtube APi will be used....but i need a sample running code for android can you provide me?